# Pandas - Using groupby to combine columns with strings - problem with TypeError message

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, consolidation

I've got a pretty simple case that, for some reason, is giving me problems.

I'm combining multiple dataframes. As a result, I'll often have the same key, but different comments for each key value.

```
KeyValue       Comment
1235           This is okay
444            Problems here
1235           Investigate further
```

I'm trying to deduplicate the keys but preserve all of the comments by consolidating them into one Comments field. The output I'd like:

```
KeyValue       Comment
1235           This is okay | Investigate further
444            Problems here
```

I've tried:

```
newdf = olddf.groupby('KeyValue')['Comment'].apply(lambda x: ' | '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

But when I do that I get

```
"TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found"
```

I've seen similar questions to mine on here (that's where I got the original code) but not sure why I'm getting this error or how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try `olddf.astype(str).groupby('KeyValue')['Comment'].apply(' | '.join).reset_index()` ..? (note - you don't need the lambda syntax for `join`)

Comment: Try `lambda x: ' | '.join(x.dropna())`. I think missing values are messing you up, since `NaN` is a float. Alternatively, you could do `olddf[olddf['Comment'].notnull()].groupby...`

Comment: @ALollz that was the problem. Tripped up again by missing values :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I converted your keyvalue to string and it works:

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.DataFrame([['KeyValue','Comment'],
[1235,'This is okay'],
[444,'Problems here'],
[1235,'Investigate further']])

mydata.columns = mydata.iloc[0]
mydata = mydata[1:]
print(mydata)

newdf = mydata.groupby(str('KeyValue'))['Comment'].apply(lambda x: ' | '.join(x)).reset_index()
print(newdf)  
0 KeyValue              Comment
1     1235         This is okay
2      444        Problems here
3     1235  Investigate further
   KeyValue                             Comment
0       444                       Problems here
1      1235  This is okay | Investigate further
```

Comment: You're casting a string to a string.. this won't do anything..?